# What do these pairs of countries have in common?

Tags: pattern, geography

The following country pairs share a very special, very distinguished, very striking property:

- Belarus and India
- Gabon and Italy
- Malta and Iraq
- Uganda and Israel

What is this common property?
Can you provide another country pair with that property?

Comment: I see that you have selected a correct answer. So is there another country pair with the same property?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Letters can be rearranged to form names of other countries.

Belarus India

> Sudan Liberia

Gabon Italy

> Libya Tonga

Malta Iraq

> Mali Qatar

Uganda Israel

> Sudan Algeria

Comment: If we are very liberal with how we define state, Estonia and Denmark can be used to form Armenia and Donetsk.

Comment: Well this was completely boring.

Answer (score 10):

I will answer to the second question, since Ayefork just showed the pattern.

**Can you provide another country pair with that property?**

> [Republic of Korea](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/South_Korea) - [Democratic Republic of Congo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Democratic_Republic_of_the_Congo)

can be easily rearranged to

> [Republic of Congo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Republic_of_the_Congo) - [Democratic Republic of Korea](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/North_Korea)

They look all the same, but they're actually different countries!

Comment: I don't think this quite works, since the question uses the short name of countries, not the formal name. The pattern doesn't work if we use "State of Israel" or "People's Democratic Republic of Algeria".

Comment: Good point, though the question doesn't specify that we must use the short name. Just let them be States!

Comment: Sudan and Liberia is another example of such a country pair.. Sudan/Liberia -> Belarus/India. Though I guess that's cheating?